# A generalization of Schur's test

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $X, Y$ be measure spaces with positive measures $d\mu, dν$, respectively. and
>   let $K$ be a measurable function on $X \times Y$. Let $u, w$ be nonnegative measurable
>   functions on $X, Y$ respectively, and assume that $u(x) > 0\space a.e.$ and $w(y) > 0\space a.e.$
>
> Suppose $1 < p < ∞$
>    and
>   $\int_X|K(x, y)|u(x)d\mu ≤ Bw(y), ν − a.e.,$
>   $\int_Y|K(x, y)|w(y)^{\frac{1}{p-1}}dν ≤ Au(x)^{\frac{1}{p-1}}, \mu − a.e.$
>   Let T be defined by $T f(x) = \int_Y
> K(x, y)f(y)dν$.
>
> Show that $T$ maps $L_p
> (Y )$ to $L_
> p
> (X)$
>   and the operator norm is bounded by $A^{1−1/p}B^{1/p}$.

In the case of $p=2$, it is Schur's test and I know its proof using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

In the general case, can we still use some Cauchy-Schwarz inequality or do we need a whole new strategy?

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: Without thinking much a about the problem: The generalization of Cauchy Schwarz to $L^p$ spaces is **Hölder's inequality**.